# IIS7, including .html in aspx, prevent caching

Tags: .net, iis-7, caching

We currently are running Windows 2008 Server Standard Edition. We are running a .net site and on some of the pages we are using includes to include some .html files that are used with our javascript. We are having an issue though with caching. When we edit one of those .html files, we can navigate to it by typing in the URL directly and see our changes. But the .net page that is pulling them in is pulling in some kind of cached copy because it is not seeing the changes.

I have tried "touching" the web.config. Tried restarting the web service. Recycling the app pool. Still can't get the changes to come up.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can try clearing the C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files folder and see if that helps. So, you stop IIS.. clear all the files and folders in the path mentioned above and start IIS again. 
Is this a precompiled application you have deployed on IIS?